# Haskell: read instance for polymorphic data type and tuples

Tags: haskell

Let's say I've got a polymorphic data type for a frame:

```hs
data Frame a = Frame {
      fdata :: V.Vector (V.Vector a)
    , frows :: Int
    , fcols :: Int
}

makeFrame :: [[a]] -> Frame a
makeFrame s = ...
```

And I want its text representation to look exactly like a list of lists:

```hs
instance Show a => Show (Frame a) where
  show (Frame m _ _) = show $ V.toList $ V.toList <$> m

instance Read a => Read (Frame a) where
  readsPrec _ value = [makeFrame $ read value, "")]
```

I was pretty happy with my read function until I found out that it doesn't really work when a frame is inside a tuple:

```
-- works
> let x = read $ show $ makeFrame [[1,2], [3,4]] :: Frame Int
> :t x
x :: Frame Int

-- doesn't work
> read $ show $ (1, makeFrame [[1,2], [3,4]]) :: (Int, Frame Int)
*** Exception: Prelude.read: no parse

-- meanwhile
> let x = read $ show $ (1, makeFrame [[1,2], [3,4]]) :: (Int, [[Int]])
> :t x
x :: (Int, [[Int]])
```

Why does an innocent embedding my data type into a tuple somehow changes the way the whole thing is parsed? What am I missing?

**UPDATE:**

Just in case, a working read implementation:

```hs
instance Read a => Read (Frame a) where
  readsPrec d v = do (lst, rst) <- readsPrec d v
                     return (makeFrame lst, rst)
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Your `readsPrec` instance always returns `""` for the remainder, meaning that it discards all characters after the end of the value it read. Here, that's the dangling `)` denoting the close of the tuple: the tuple can't be parsed, because you threw that character away.

You need to use the `readsPrec` instance of the thing you're parsing, to know how many characters it consumed. I'll use a simpler newtype than yours, so as to be compilable with no external dependencies:

```
newtype Wrapper a = Wrapper a

instance Show a => Show (Wrapper a) where
  show (Wrapper x) = 'w':show x

instance Read a => Read (Wrapper a) where
  readsPrec n ('w':s) = [(Wrapper x, r) | (x, r) <- readsPrec n s]
```

This works, but if I replace my `Read` instance with one analogous to yours, I get the same error: it can't parse while inside of another data structure.

```
-- totally broken instance
instance Read a => Read (Wrapper a) where
  readsPrec _ ('w':s) = [(Wrapper $ read s, "")]
```

Comment: Thank you. I thought my readsPrec is not called at all for some reason because if add trace there, it doesn't show anything: readsPrec _ value = [(makeFrame $ read $ trace ("--> " ++ value) value, "")]). Probably it has something to do with the way exceptions are displayed.

Comment: Btw, do you know if there's a simple function that can read a list *and* tell me how many symbols its text representation takes?

Comment: @DanKruchinin: It might be easier to just read in a list of lists and convert it to your frame data type. Something like `readsPrec = makeFrame . readsPrec`, except with whatever additional arguments you need to pass around to make it typecheck.

Comment: @TikhonJelvis Not sure I get what you mean. Say, there's a string "(1, [[1,2],[3,4]], 2, [[5,6],[7,8]])". How do you suggest to parse it?

Comment: @DanKruchinin: `readsPrec` just defines how to parse a `Frame`. The "prec" part is what lets other parsing functions nest frames (prec stands for "precedence"). So as long as you have a correct implementation of `readsPrec` for `Frame`, parsing nested data structures should work too. Since `[[a]]` already has a correct version of `readsPrec`, you can just reuse it.